# Need to retain the Info Window even after Auto Refresh of Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I have designed a Marker and an Info Window. Now the location is being fetched from a Database every 2 seconds and the marker position gets updated. The Info Window is shown on Marker Click. Now whenever the marker gets updated, the Info Window disappears. If I put the Info Window inside repeat function then the Info Window keeps on showing. I need to show the Info Window on Marker Click and disappear on clicking Marker again. It should not disappear on the refreshing of Marker position.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Log.e(TAG,"Getting Repeated Location");
    scheduleSendLocation();

    myLat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    myLng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Lat:"+myLat+"\tLng:"+myLng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (myLat==0 && myLng==0) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Invalid Location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        Intent dev = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DevicesNavActivity.class);
        startActivity(dev);
    }

    else if (myLat==null && myLng==null) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        Intent dev = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DevicesNavActivity.class);
        startActivity(dev);
    }

    else {

        CustomInfoWindowActivity customInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindowActivity(this);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(customInfoWindow);

        final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        final Marker[] m = new Marker[1];

        LatLng loc = new LatLng(myLat,myLng);
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 17f);
        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);

        handler.postDelayed(runnable2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                LatLng location = new LatLng(myLat, myLng);

                //Adding Marker to Location

                markerOptions.position(location)
                        .title("Marker")
                        .snippet("My Marker")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

                myLat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                myLng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

                mMap.clear();
                m[0] = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(myLat, myLng); //Store these lat lng values somewhere. These should be constant.
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 17f);
                mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                handler.postDelayed(this, TIME);
            }
        }, TIME);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                //Displaying the Info Window
                InfoWindowData info = new InfoWindowData();
                info.setName("Co-Ordinates of "+myimei);
                info.setLatitude(latitude);
                info.setLongitude(longitude);

                m[0].setTag(info);
                m[0].showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried just updating marker position with `myMarker.setPosition(newLatLng);` rather than the remove/add approach presented in your post - you'd also have to remove the `clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

after you add marker after clearing marker call showInfowindow on marker

```
m[0] = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
 m[0].showInfoWindow();
```

this should do the trick

Comment: The Activity is crashing

Comment: can you share crash log?

Comment: Shared it in answer